# How to change quantity input field to "Sold Out" in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce, product

I'm trying to add condition, if product is out of stock, then don't display quantity field, just text "Sold Out".

How to do this?

When I'm trying to edit this in `/templates/global/quantity-input.php`, then cart isn't working.

Any ideas?

Comment: Add your code so I can see what you've done wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly , when your product is out of stock you want to show "sold out" ,so add to your functions.php this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'display_sold_out_woocommerce' );

function display_sold_out_woocommerce() {
    global $product;

    if ( !$product->is_in_stock() ) {
        echo '<span class="soldout">' . __( 'Sold Out', 'woocommerce' ) . '</span>';
    }
}
```